# How do I get access to the numbers or score that i've given the words in my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, text-files, average

This is the code:

```
word_count = {}

with open(file, "r") as fi:
    for line in fi:
        words = line.split()  

        for word in words:
            word = word.lower()

            if word not in word_count: 
                word_count[word] = 0 

            word_count[word] += 1

    print(word_count)
```

Output:

```
{'thou': 2, 'ancient,': 1, 'free': 1}
```

I want to somehow get access to the numbers 2,1 and 1 so I can get the average usage of the words in my text file. So my question is how do I do it?

I've tried to use the dictionary somehow to add up the numbers in the dictionary but in it, I have both the words and the numbers so I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".

Comment: Do you want to add 2+1+1 and divide by 3? 
So from your example, get 1.33?

Comment: You should remove the carriage returns caused by line reading, thus should have `words = line.rtrip().split()`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`dict.values()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_values.asp) method. Like this:

```
word_freq = {'thou': 2, 'ancient,': 1, 'free': 1}

avg = sum(word_freq.values())/len(word_freq)
print(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to somehow get access to the numbers 2,1 and 1 so I can get the
> average usage of the words in my text file. So my question is how do I
> do it?*

Well, there are many ways to do this, but I think the fastest way is this one:

```
total = sum(word_count.values())
```

Then to get the average simply use the `/` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use loop with dicts if you want to change anything with the value.

```
sum_words = 0
for i in word_count.values():
    print(i)
    sum_words += i
print("Avg: " + str(sum_words/len(word_count)))
```

Comment: Well... no, you're overwriting the same "sum" function that you should have used. Never do this.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to access values in a dictionary is by indexing it

```py
thou_count = word_count['thou']
```

If you aren't sure if a key is in your dictionary and you want to try to access it you can use `get` and provide a default value

```py
thee_count = word_count.get('thee', -1)
```

If you want to get all the values, you can use `word_count.values()` which returns a result you can iterate through. Oftentimes though you will want to convert the result to a list

```py
print(list(word_count.values()))
```

Similarly, you can access keys with `word_count.keys()` or you can iterate through key-value pairs using

```py
for key, value in word_count.items():
    print(f"{key=}, {value=}")
```